# Inserting check boxes next to MySQL database output in the form of HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, html-table

I've been trying to insert check boxes next to values retrieved from a MySQL table  and the output is in the form of a HTML table.

[image]

The output is on the same page as the query form which will retrieve the values in the form of the table above. Now, I wish to insert check boxes beside each row/entry received from the database and use it to update the notification_sent column in the database, but so far I've hit a roadblock with this.

Comment: sounds purely like an html\css issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one more td with the checkbox code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="notification_sent[]"/></td>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble inserting it within the php tags. Sorry if I sound like a noob.